# While loop is not working

Tags: c, while-loop, syntax-error

```
while(!s.isEmpty() && prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())) {}
```

The above statement in my program is executed correctly

But the below statement gives me emptyStackError

```
while(prec(c) <= prec(s.peek()) && !s.isEmpty()) {}
```

The changes I did is only in the while statement which gives me error?
Why the working in the both cases were different??

Comment: "short cicuit evaluation" GIYF

Comment: && is an excluding operator, which means, that first your condition is checked for `!s.IsEmpty()` and if it's **true**, only then the `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())` part is checked. Probably `!s.isEmpty()` always gives **false**, so `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek()))` was not checked. When you changed the code, it was checked first and you got the empty stack error.

Comment: You appear to be invoking a class function with `s.isEmpty()`, which kind of implies that this isn't C. ???

Answer (score 2):

In your `while` condition, there are 2 checks, which are `and` together with `&&`:

```
while(!s.isEmpty() && prec(c) <= prec(s.peek()))
```

These 2 check sequences matter. First you need to check whether `stack` is empty. If it is, it doesn't carry with the second check. If it is not empty, it does `s.peek()` on the stack for the `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())` check.

On the other hand, if you have:

```
while(prec(c) <= prec(s.peek()) && !s.isEmpty())
```

The second check `!s.isEmpty()` is basically useless, as it didn't prevent code to carry out the `s.peek()`, in case of `empty stack`. So it throws `empty stack error / exception`.

Hence `s.isEmpty()` has to come first before the second check.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!s.isEmpty() && prec(c) <= prec(s.peek()))
```

• In this while loop, it checks whether your stack is empty or not and only if it's not empty it will `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())`

```
while(prec(c) <= prec(s.peek()) && !s.isEmpty())
```

• In this while loop it will first compare `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())` and only if true, it will check whether the stack is empty or not.

The second loop gives you the error because if there is nothing in your stack it will still try to compare `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())` before coming to realise that your stack is empty.

Just ask yourself, what is it comparing `prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())` if your stack is empty ?

So just to make clear you inderstand => **Your loop terminates when prec(c) <= prec(s.peek())... but it also terminates when your stack is empty. The second while loop compares values where one of those values happen to be coming from your stack. if your stack is empty, what should it compare ?**